# Converting a plain Uint8List to image widget

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and I have a question regarding a small project of mine.

I'm trying to show an image I'm receiving through a socket.
I have an Uint8List representing the image matrix (not encoded in any way), and I have succeded transforming it into an Image widget with the following code:

```
Image im = Image.fromBytes(1280, 1024, frameData, format: Format.luminance);
var jpgImage = encodeJpg(im);
.
.
//In Widget:
return Image.memory(jpgImage, gaplessPlayback: true);
```

and it works, but it takes too much time.
I see that the encodeJpg function takes at least 150ms, which is too much for me because each such image is a part of a streaming video.

My question is, how can I transform a plain(not encoded) Uint8List - representing a regular matrix, 0-256 values, to an Image widget, in the most efficient way?

Thank you!

Comment: `MemoryImage(uint8List)` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/MemoryImage-class.html

Comment: above or Image.memory(uint8List) https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html

Comment: `MemoryImage` (and equivalently, `Image.memory`) expect the raw bytes to be of a PNG image, JPEG image, etc.  I'm not sure that they would recognize a raw stream of RGB values (and wouldn't know those bytes represent RGB, BGR, RGBA, ARGB, etc. data).  The [`Image` class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html) (from `dart:ui`) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Bitmap` to create a Uint8List with header that the `Image.memory()` can parse.

as in https://pub.dev/packages/bitmap:

```
import 'package:bitmap/bitmap.dart';

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.fromHeadful(imageWidth, imageHeight, theListOfInts); // Not async

// ..

Uint8List headedBitmap = bitmap.buildHeaded();

// ..
child: Image.memory(headedBitmap)
// ..
```

Answer (score 1):

The image widget has few constructors and one of them is memory.

Check `Image.memory(bytes)` factory constructor.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html